# How do I push only certain refs and files beginning at a certain commit in GIT

Tags: git, github, branch

I have a local GIT repository for my PhD. I want to create a private repository on GitHub which only contains the main PhD document and articles (Markdown Files) for my supervisors.

I created a new branch in which I deleted everything and then I checkedout specific files from the man PhD aranch and articles from article branches like this:

```
git checkout phd_main Dissertation/dissertation.md
```

thus the working tree in my supervisory branch only contains the path I just checkedout.

However, when I commit and push to the GitHub  repository all files and references are pushed and everything can be read. The interesting but unfortunate situation is that locally I just have the `Dissertation/dissertation.md` file in my branch but remotely I have everything.

How can I have a branch that contains just specifically checkedout files and also just pushes these files and refs in a version starting from the first commit in that branch.

Comment: Since git is a version control tool, it's natural that it stores the old versions as well. If that is not what you want, you probably should not be using a version control tool in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Create your new branch with `git checkout --orphan branchname`. This will create a branch called `branchname` that has no history, which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To create an empty branch, you need to use

```
git checkout --orphan <branchname>
```

Next, remove all files in the directory except those md files, then do

```
git commit -m <commit message>
git push origin <branchname>
```

If you want to make sure only .md files are commited on this branch, create and commit .gitignore file with the content

```
*
!*.md
```

Comment: unfortunately all the other files are still pushed to the new repository. I think because they remain part of the commit history.

Comment: Did you remove those files after you checkout the new branch?

Comment: yes, that is the strange thing. I don't have them locally anymore but they reappear in the remote repo when I push. I alos don't really understand why

Comment: Perhaps they were already staged? Run `git status` to make sure the index is empty, if it's not, `git rm` the files.